# substring from main string using CString library functions

Tags: c++11, c-strings

Copy a substring from main string using CString library functions.

```
CString  FilterCriteria ="MESSAGE=2 AND READ = 2 AND Instance=\'SMS/MMS\' 
AND Folder=\'inbox\'";
CString  o_filter;
```

Now, i want to copy `Instance=\'SMS/MMS\' AND Folder=\'inbox\'` from `FilterCriteria` to `o_filteredFilterCriteria`.

Expected result:

```
o_filter = Instance=\'SMS/MMS\' AND Folder=\'inbox\'.
```

Program:

```
int Pos = FilterCriteria.find(instance); 
int First_Pos = FilterCriteria.find("'");
string temp_str = FilterCriteria.substr(First_Pos+1);
string temp_str =FilterCriteria.
int Second_Pos = temp_str.find("'");  

string tempInstance = FilterCriteria.substr(Pos, First_Pos+Second_Pos-
Pos+2);

temp_str = "";

Pos = FilterCriteria.find(folder);// folder position
string Fold_Str = FilterCriteria.substr(Pos);//string after the folder 
First_Pos = Fold_Str.find("'");// first occurence of string
temp_str = Fold_Str.substr(First_Pos+1);// string after '
Second_Pos = temp_str.find("'");// first occurence of ' in string after '
string tempFolder=originalFilterCriteria.substr(Pos, First_Pos+Second_Pos-
Pos+2);

if ( !tempInstance.isEmpty())
{
    o_filter = " AND ";
    o_filter += tempInstance;
}

if (!tempFolder.isEmpty())
{
    o_filter = " AND ";
    o_filter += tempFolder;
}

This code works for string.h library. The same code doesn't work for CString 
functions as CString library doesn't have substr() function.
```

Comment: You might be looking for [`CString::Mid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx#cstringt__mid)

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik. This is helpful.

Comment: CString::const_iterator Pos = FilterCriteria.find(instance);            
CString Inst_str = FilterCriteria.getRight(Pos);
CString::const_iterator First_Pos = Inst_str.find("'");
CString temp_str = Inst_str.getRight(First_Pos+1);
CString::const_iterator Second_Pos = temp_str.find("'");  
CString tempInstance = FilterCriteria.getMid(Pos, (UInt32) 
First_Pos+Second_Pos-Pos+2); (error: cannot convert 
CString::const_iterator to integer in second argument)
temp_str = "";    
How to convert CString::const_iterator to integer as getMid() needs 
second argument as integer.

Comment: You must be using some `CString` class I'm not familiar with. [The one I'm familiar with](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx) doesn't have a member named `getMid`, nor `find` nor `getRight`. I no longer have any idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 5):

I have also searched for an equivalence.

A `std::string` used like this:

```
stdString.substr(begin, end - begin + 1);
```

is equivalent to a MFC `CString` used like this:

```
mfcString.Mid(begin, end - begin + 1);

//or
mfcString.Right(mfcString.GetLength() - begin).Left(end - begin + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess `Find` and cut with `Mid` will do the trick. See the below example for a better understanding.

> I have a CString as path = _T("StackOverflow is the best platform for the programmer.")
> I want the string as "StackOverflow is the best " only. So first I find "platform"
> then cut the portion.

```cpp
CString path = _T("StackOverFlow is the best platform for the programmer.");
int pos = path.Find(_T("platform"));
path = path.Mid(0, pos);

// Output:
// path = "StackOverflow is the best "

// or

int length = path.GetLength();
pos = path.Find(_T("platform"));
path = path.Mid(pos, length);

// Output:
// path = "platform for the programmer."
```